# New test module in django with python 2 not working

Tags: python, django, selenium

I was following the TDD at  [O'Reilly](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com)  and I tried to make the functional_tests to run in isolation as shown [here](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000754/ch06.html#_ensuring_test_isolation_in_functional_tests) 
But I'm getting the error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: App with label functional_tests could not be found
```

Directory structure is as below:

├── functional_tests/

│   ├── **init**.py

│   └── tests.py

├── apps/

│   ├── models.py

...

tests.py contains following code:

```
from django.test.client import Client
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


class FunctionalTest(LiveServerTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)
        self.c = Client()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(
            username="admin", email="admin@agiliq.com", password="admin")

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    def test_admin_login(self):
        self.browser.get(self.live_server_url)
        # login = self.browser.find_element_by_link_text("Login")
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run your tests with `python manage.py test functional_tests` as it shown in the article you should keep `functional_tests` app in the `INSTALLED_APPS`. And make sure your PYTHONPATH is set up properly.